# Local storage not working with drop down menu

Tags: storage, local

I have a problem with saving data to storage.

I am using text fields and drop down menus.

Text field are working fine with saving but dropdown menu ain't working.

As you can see i am using local storage from html 5 to save everything

Does anyone know what the problem is ?

Woonplaats and favomuziek are with dropdown menu

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if (!window.localStorage){
        function createCookie(name,value,days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }
            else var expires = "";
            document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
        }

        function readCookie(name) {
            var result = ""
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0){
                        result = c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
                    }else{
                        result = "";
                    }
                }
                return(result);
            }
            localStorage = (function () {
            return {
                setItem: function (key, value) {
                    createCookie(key, value, 3000)
                },

                getItem: function (key) {
                    return(readCookie(key));
                }
            };
        })();
    }

    load_settings();

    $('#gebruikersprofiel').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        save_settings();
    });
});

function save_settings(){
    localStorage.setItem("voornaam", $("#voornaam").val());
    localStorage.setItem("achternaam", $("#achternaam").val());
    localStorage.setItem("woonplaats", $("#woonplaats").val());
    localStorage.setItem("favomuziek", $("#favomuziek").val());

    apply_preferences_to_page();
}

function apply_preferences_to_page(){
    $("body").css("voornaam", $("#voornaam").val());
    $("body").css("achternaam", $("#achternaam").val());
    $("body").css("woonplaats", $("#woonplaats").val() );
    $("body").css("favomuziek", $("#favomuziek").val() );
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    if (!window.localStorage){
        function createCookie(name,value,days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }
            else var expires = "";
            document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
        }

        function readCookie(name) {
            var result = ""
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0){
                    result = c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
                }else{
                    result = "";
                }
            }
            return(result);
        }
        localStorage = (function () {
            return {
                setItem: function (key, value) {
                    createCookie(key, value, 3000)
                },

                getItem: function (key) {
                    return(readCookie(key));
                }
            };
        })();
    }

    load_settings();

    $('#gebruikersprofiel').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        save_settings();
    });
});

function save_settings(){
    localStorage.setItem("voornaam", $("#voornaam").val());
    localStorage.setItem("achternaam", $("#achternaam").val());
    localStorage.setItem("woonplaats", $("#woonplaats").val());
    localStorage.setItem("favomuziek", $("#favomuziek").val());

    apply_preferences_to_page();
}

function apply_preferences_to_page(){
    $("body").css("voornaam", $("#voornaam").val());
    $("body").css("achternaam", $("#achternaam").val());
    $("body").css("woonplaats", $("#woonplaats").val() );
    $("body").css("favomuziek", $("#favomuziek").val() );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't save anything if i choose something from the dropdown menu.

Comment: I have a new code but with this one i can't save anything :S, it's showing me old storage information ..

Comment: You might want to set a breakpoint at the first statement of `save_settings` function. Step into the code one at a time and check the value that is to be passed to `localStorage.setItem`.

Comment: Jay can you look at the new code for me :) tnx!